# How to link to a file, not to a class?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using with composer the library FusionChart, which is not built for composer use. So I create an artifact package with it.

The class loading works well, but I've a problem with a file I need to include in some case. This file doesn't contains any class, it's just a file which is directly called from an ajax request, and it produces a response embedding a file.

At the moment I include as following in my route controller:

```
ob_start();
include(__DIR__ . '\\..\\..\\..\\vendor\\fusioncharts\\fusioncharts\\FCExporter.php');
return ob_get_flush();
```

But I already break twice the path this week, and I wonder if composer may offer a workaround to point or to load this file without wrinting a relative path?

Comment: You can set the class/file maps in your composer.json file. https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap. But you will still need to assert some discipline over your directory structure.

Comment: @Flosculus It doesn't load the file on-demand doesn't it? The file must be included only on special case otherwise it breaks the app